# two delimiters output formatting javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, split

I thought this would be easier, but running into a weird issue.
I want to split the following:

```
theList = 'firstword:subwordone;subwordtwo;subwordthree;secondword:subwordone;thirdword:subwordone;subwordtwo;';
```

and have the output be

```
firstword
    subwordone
    subwordtwo
    subwordthree
secondword
    subwordone
thirdword
    subwordone
    subwordtwo
```

The caveat is sometimes the list can be

```
theList = 'subwordone;subwordtwo;subwordthree;subwordfour;'
```

ie no ':' substrings to print out, and that would look like just

```
    subwordone
    subwordtwo
    subwordthree
    subwordfour
```

I have tried variations of the following base function, trying recursion, but either get into infinite loops, or undefined output.

```
function getUl(theList, splitOn){
    var r = '<ul>';
    var items = theList.split(splitOn);

    for(var li in items){
        r += ('<li>'+items[li]+'</li>');
    }
    r += '</ul>';
    return r;
}
```

The above function is just my starting point and obviously doesnt work, just wanted to show what path I am going down, and to be shown the correct path, if this is totally off base.

Comment: Do you have control over this datastructure? If yes, you should change the format to something like this: `'A:1;2;3|B:1|C:1;2'` to easily distinguish between separators of values and the beginning of a new key-value(s) assignment. Then you could do some simple `split()` and you are done.

Comment: @Christoph: Or save it as JSON or some other "array" format.

Comment: I believe the second element type(ones with a ';' following it) always has that appended, as it isnt know if it is the last one in the data set.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need two cases, and the difference between the two is whether there is a `:` in your string.

```
if(theList.indexOf(':') == -1){
    //Handle the no sublist case
} else {
    //Handle the sublist case
}
```

Starting with the no sublist case, we develop the simple pattern:

```
var elements = theList.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var element = elements[i];
    //Add your element to your list
}
```

Finally, we apply that same pattern to come up with the implementation for the sublist case:

```
var elements = theList.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var element = elements[i];
    if(element.indexOf(':') == -1){
        //Add your simple element to your list
    } else {
        var innerElements = element.split(':');

        //Add innerElements[0] as your parent element

        //Add innerElements[1] as your child element

        //Increment i until you hit another element with ':', adding the single elements each increment as child elements.

        //Decrement i so it considers the element with the ':' as a parent element.

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried something like this, but the recursive nature ends up infinite.

Comment: @user1700945:  My last update shows comments on how your sublist implementation might work with the current format.  Note that it your current format of passing the information is not very friendly to work with, so if it's possible to reformat it into something like `{A:[1,2,3],B:[1],C:[1,2]}`, you could just `eval` it to get a JavaScript object that would be easily work with.

Comment: reformatting the data is out of our control, and making it complaex like that is not really an option :(

Comment: @user1700945:  Ok, then I think if you implement my above comments, you shouldn't end up with infinite loops.  Let me know if you run into any issues and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: @user1700945:  What does your code look like?  A [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the current list to add items to, and create a new list when you find a colon in an item:

```
var baseParent = $('ul'), parent = baseParent;
$.each(theList.split(';'), function(i, e) {
  if (e.length) {
    var p = e.split(':');
    if (p.length > 1) {
      baseParent.append($('<li>').append($('<span>').text(p[0])).append(parent = $('<ul>')));
    }
    parent.append($('<li>').text(p[p.length - 1]));
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/eWQpR/

Demo for `"1;2;3;4;"`: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/eWQpR/2/

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

var baseParent = $('ul'), parent = baseParent;

Comment: @user1700945: It seems that you haven't included jQuery.

Comment: extjs is including it, so not sure why that error is coming up :(

Comment: @user1700945: Have you put the code below the point where it's included?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant solution but this does the trick. (**See edit below**)

```
function showLists(text) {
    // Build the lists
    var lists = {'': []};
    for(var i = 0, listKey = ''; i < text.length; i += 2) {
        if(text[i + 1] == ':') {
            listKey = text[i];
            lists[listKey] = [];
        } else {
            lists[listKey].push(text[i]);
        }
    }

    // Show the lists
    for(var listName in lists) {
        if(listName) console.log(listName);

        for(var j in lists[listName]) {
            console.log((listName ? '    ' : '') + lists[listName][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Another interesting approach you could take would be to start by breaking it up into sections (assuming `text` equals one of the examples you gave):

```
var lists = text.match(/([\w]:)?([\w];)+/g);
```

Then you have broken down the problem into simpler segments

```
for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    var listParts = lists[i].split(':');
    if(listParts.length == 1) {
        console.log(listParts[0].split(';').join("\n"));
    } else {
        console.log(listParts[0]);
        console.log('    ' + listParts[1].split(';').join("\n    "));
    }
}
```

Comment: this outputted all my text in a single line, going horizontal, and all the words(represented by A B C and 1 2 3 in my example) are printed out straight, no indention.  I feel this is not the solution either.

Comment: OK, well it's easy to change the formatting. Just separate the parsing from the display. If you run that in a Javascript console (Firebug or Chrome Javascript Console) it will look exactly as you showed. In your question you showed it indented so I made the output match what you demonstrated exactly. The point of this is to give you a direction to go, you still need to modify it for your specific case, since I don't really now what that is. Is it helpful in solving your parsing problem? There are two different ways that are equally effective in parsing what you showed.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet displays the list depending on your requirements

```
   var str  = 'subwordone;subwordtwo;subwordthree;';
    var a = []; var arr = [];
    a = str;
    var final = [];


    function split_string(a){

        var no_colon = true;

        for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

    if(a[i] == ':'){
    no_colon = false;
    var temp;
    var index = a[i-1];
    var rest = a.substring(i+1);
    final[index] = split_string(rest);
    return a.substring(0, i-2);
    }

    } 

    if(no_colon) return a;

    }

    function display_list(element, index, array) {
        $('#results ul').append('<li>'+element+'</li>');
    }


    var no_colon_string = split_string(a).split(';');

    if(no_colon_string){
        $('#results').append('<ul><ul>');
    }
    no_colon_string.forEach(display_list);

    console.log(final);
```

working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjacF/2/)** here